# Execute javascript file in child process within Electron

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I've got an Electron app with Angular inside (last versions). I need to execute javascript (not typescript) file from the project in child process (some heavy things that I don't want to execute syncronously).
Tried this solutions:
1. Created function `Loader`, put all content there:

```
export function Loader() { console.log(111); }
```

Then in component that creates child process:

```
import { Loader } from 'some/path/to/loader.js';

public doSomething(): void {
  fork(
    Loader,
    [ ... some string args here ],
    { env: { 'ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE': '1' } }
  )
    .on(
      'error',
      (error: Error): void => console.error(error)
    )
    .on(
      'exit',
      async (code: number | null): Promise<void> => {
        if (code === 0) {
          console.log(`Finished with code ${code}`);
          await this.someMethod();
        } else {
          console.error(`Exit code is ${code}`);
        }
      }
    );
}
```

2.Removing Loader function wrapper, js file looks like

```
console.log(1111);
```

In component:

```
public doSomething(): void {
  fork(
    require.resolve('some/path/to/loader.js'),
    [ ... some string args here ],
    { env: { 'ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE': '1' } }
  )
    .on(// The same event handling
```

For both cases child process **in prod mode or release build** fails with code 1. The same code placed to Electron's main.ts file works.

How can I fix child process execution in the place where I'm calling it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably might want to use WebWorkers.

You can move some of your heavy code to web-workers and keep your main thread non-blocked.

```js
let win = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegrationInWorker: true
  }
})
```

and then

```js
let worker = new Worker('script.js')
```

https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/multithreading

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the Renderer, I believe you need to use [remote](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote)

something like this could work:

```
const { spawn } = window.remote.require('child_process')
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr'])

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`)
})

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`)
})
```

in the above you'd need to attach remote to window:

```
 <script>
     this.window.remote = require('electron').remote;
 </script>
```